# Do you know the names of universities starting with definite article "the"?

Tags: names, titles, toponyms

Do you know the names of universities starting with definite article "the"?

Such as:

1. The London School of Economics and Political Science
2. The Chicago School of Professional Psychology
3. The Hague University of Applied Sciences

Thank you for answering my question.

Comment: The Ohio State University.

Comment: That...would be a very long list that I do not think we are equipped to answer.  You would do better consulting a Department of Education list of colleges.

Comment: Except you might have to [wait a while.](http://ope.ed.gov/accreditation/)

Comment: Ah yes...that would be a problem.  And would also be the source I would go to if looking for such a list.

Comment: What is it with [universities and the definite article](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/130731/definite-article-the-before-name-of-university)?

Comment: The University of Michigan (where I teach) is so insistent on the definite article that the title pages of Ph.D. theses here must contain "A dissertation submitted ... in The University of Michigan", with "The" capitalized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In Great- Britain :**

The Courtauld Institute of Art, University of London
London

The London School of Economics and Political Science
London

The Robert Gordon University
Aberdeen

The University of Buckingham
Buckingham

The University of Edinburgh

Edinburgh

The University of Hull
Hull ...

The University of Manchester
Manchester

The University of Northampton
Northampton

The University of Nottingham
Nottingham ...

The University of Sheffield

Sheffield

The University of Warwick
Coventry

The University of Winchester
Winchester

The University of York
York

Answer (score 0):

[This source](http://www.utexas.edu/world/univ/alpha/) might be able to help you out. As well as [this](http://www.50states.com/college/), [this](http://www.clas.ufl.edu/au/) and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_state_universities_in_the_United_States).  They differ in how they list colleges with a definite "The" article, so choose whichever one best suits your needs.